# What is the best way to know in activity method which fragment is calling that method

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a common method to get image from gallery in activity which is accessed by different fragments what is the best way to know in activity method which fragment is calling this method so that I can put appropriate conditions.

I have tried by passing a string in fragment but is there any other clean way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Blockquote I have a common method to get image from gallery in activity which is accessed by different fragments what is the best way to know in activity method which fragment is calling this method so that I can put appropriate conditions.

Could you provide more details on what you are trying to achieve?
If I got it right, you have a method in your Activity that is accessed by different fragments. Is it right? If yes, then there is a high chance that it is not correct. Let me elaborate on this: by letting fragments invoke a method inside the hosting activity you are coupling them to the activity. What if you need to attach the same Fragment to different activities? Anyway, this is not always the case. For example, if you already know that these fragments will always be used with this particular activity, then it is OK.
In general, the communication between activities and fragments is achieved by means of interfaces to allow components to remain decoupled. I higly reccomend you to read the official docs on the topic [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate).

Anyway, if you want to have such function, and you are using Kotlin, you could exploit [reified parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters). For example, in your activity you could have:

```
inline fun <reified T> invokerName() = T::class.simpleName // Do something with the class
```

that you can invoke this way:

```
activity.invokerName<Foo>()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the Fragment class like this :

```
    (requireActivity() as YourActivity).method(this::class)
```

and in your activity take all available information about this class :

```
    fun method(comesFromClass: KClass<out Fragment>) {
        val simpleName = comesFromClass.simpleName
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Does this work like we have #instanceof keyword in java?